# Infrared image processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab

i would like to process infrared imaging in Matlab. Any kind of processing or techniques. 
Is there any built-in function in Matlab? 
And can anyone suggest any books or articles,as well as resources for sample Far Infrared images.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect that processing infrared images will, in general, be different from processing visible-colour images ?

Comment: yes, that is my initial thought. or rather, i expect specific kind of processing available specifically for infrared images. so my assumption is wrong, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/). There, you find plenty of built-in functionality for denoising and segmentation of any kind of images.

For more detailed answers, I suggest that you let us know in more detail what kind of processing that you want to do.

**EDIT**

Infrared images are normally grayscale images. Thus, it is very straightforward to false-color them by mapping the gray levels to colors (i.e. by applying a different colormap).

```
%# load a grayscale image
img = imread('coins.png');

%# display the image
figure
imshow(img,[]);

%# false-color
colormap('hot')
```

For more information about general techniques, you may want to [Google 'infrared image processing'](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=infrared+image+processing) and start looking at the hits related to your specific application.

In general, processing of infrared images is not different from processing other grayscale images. What specific algorithms you apply depends very much on the image and the purpose of the processing.

Comment: I am quite familiar with the toolbox, but never work on infrared image processing before. How about doing a pseudo-coloring on a near-infrared image? I don't have many specific processing in mind - that is what I am looking for - what are the techniques/processing normally used in infrared imaging. 

btw, thanks for reponding!

Answer (score 0):

LWIR imagery can be used for a large number of different applications. In general, each application domain has its own history, terminology and mathematical conventions.

As an example, we can use LWIR imagery for:

- Detecting faulty components or components that are likely to fail.
- Medical imaging for diagnosis of skin disorders.
- Finding humans in Search & Rescue or border-control applications.
- Detecting & classifying aircraft, missiles, vehicles etc... for various defense applications.
- Geographical or Oceanographic research (using LWIR satellite imagery).

Each of these applications will rely upon very different techniques. The image processing toolbox may well be useful for some of these application areas, but, in general, you need to look at resources (software, textbooks, journals etc...) that are specific to the application domain or the specific sensor system that you will be using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the processing infrared images  in general will not be different from processing visible-color images. As far as i came to know, during the processing of infrared images, we have to use raw data image which contains temperature information rather than pseudo color image which contains only the color intensity from 0-255.